# Get weights of a given path of a graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph

I have following connections for a graph:

```
s = [1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7];
t = [2 4 8 3 7 4 6 5 6 8 7 8];
weights = [10 10 1 10 1 10 1 1 12 12 12 12];
G = digraph(s,t,weights)
```

Now I want to get weights of a given path. For example, for a path connected `[1 2 3 6 7]` has weights `[10 10 1 12]`.

How I can get that weight vector when I give the path vector?

**ADD:**
Actually I get all paths between `1` and `7` using `[paths,edgepaths] = allpaths(G,1,7)`. Since this returns only paths and edges and it does not return corresponding weights, I need an own code.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `distances` to get the matrix of distances - if you provide your route as input arguments then the diagonal will give your desired weights array

```
route = [1 2 3 6 7];
weights = diag( distances( G, route(1:end-1), route(2:end) ) );
```

This has the disadvantage of making a potentially large intermediate matrix if your route is long. It will also obfuscate paths via other nodes, for instance

```
route = [1 2 3 5 7];
```

This doesn't have a direct route, nodes 3 and 5 are not neighbours. However, you can get between the two via node 6, so the output in `weights` would be the total of the two edge weights (including sign since this is a digraph). Nodes which are completely disconnected will have distance `Inf`.

Comment: Actually I get all paths between `1` and `7` using `[paths,edgepaths] = allpaths(G,1,7)`. Since this returns only paths and edges and it does not return corresponding weights, I need my own code.

Comment: @Frey I don't understand your comment, does my answer not give you the result you asked for in the question?